# How to remove a first row in awk script?

Tags: unix, awk, operating-system

Question:

```
roll|name|marks1|marks2|marks3
1|ena|2|3|4
2|img|5|6|7
3|skh|8|9|10
4|dji|11|12|13
```

Calculate the total sum of each student and display it along with name.

This is my code:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="|";OFS="-"} {sum=0} {for(i=3;i<=NF;i++) {sum+=$i} {print $2, sum}}'
```

o/p:

```
name-0
ena-9
img-18
skh- 27
dji- 36
```

I want to remove `name-0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
{sum=0}
```

with

```
NR==1{next} {sum=0}
```

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, **NR**, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)